# Elements By ClassName Failing

Tags: javascript

I am creating sliding menus in JavaScript, and the following is my `init()` function:

```
function init() {
   var menus = new Array();
   var allElems = document.getElementsByTagName("*");

   for (var i = 0; i < allElems.length; i++) {
      alert(allElems[i]);
      if (allElems[i].className == "navG") {
      alert(allElems[i]);
      menus.push(allElems[i]); 
      }
   }

   /* assign the openMenu function to the onclick event for each
      Menus item */
    for (var i = 0; i < menus.length; i++) {
       alert(menus[i]);
       menus[i].onclick=openMenu;
    }

    document.getElementById("logo").onclick = closeMenu;
    document.getElementById("linkList").onclick = closeMenu;
    document.getElementById("main").onclick = closeMenu;
}
```

The problem seems to be in the first for loop. This is definitely the correct class name..just for reference, this is the type of HTML that I am referring to:

```
<div class="navG" id="gallery1" style="position: absolute; top: 180px; left: -150px; " >
```

Is there an obvious, or not so obvious reason, that this is not adding the elements to menus?

Comment: What is `menus.length` just before the second loop starts? Also, the three `.onclick = closeMenu();` lines at the end should (probably) be `.onclick = closeMenu;` (no parentheses). (Also, why do you even have the second loop and the `menus` array? Can't you just assign `allElems[i].onclick=openMenu` directly in the first loop?)

Comment: It gives me zero..that could be a problem, eh?

Comment: That's weird, since you said in the comment below that the second alert in the loop is working. Are you sure the code in the question is the same as the code you're actually running?

Comment: I may have made a mistake before, it seems that what I thought was the second loop working was a misplaced alert :/. So there is still nothing being stored in menus, regardless of the quotation marks.

Comment: But does the alert inside `if (allElems[i].className == "navG") {` show up or not? Note that if the elements have more than one class assigned like `<div class="navG someclass" ...>` your `== "navG"` comparison won't work.

Comment: P.S. Your code seems to work fine here: http://jsfiddle.net/rtn8P/

Comment: It doesn't seem to work on my server..(http://orca.st.usm.edu/~tbonnet2/440/p5/tutorial04solution.htm). After a bit of finagling, it seems that no alert inside of a for loop is working. I wonder what the difference is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the page you linked to, in your `family.js` script, this line:

```
window.onLoad = init();
```

says to run the `init` function *immediately* and assign its return value to `window.onLoad`. Because it is running immediately the actual document hasn't been parsed yet so it doesn't find any of your elements. You need to say this:

```
window.onload = init;
```

which assigns a reference to the `init` function to `window.onload` so that that function will be run *later* after all of the elements have been parsed.

Also `onload` should have a lowercase `l`.

(There are some other problems in your code, e.g., you don't seem to have elements with the ids `"linkList"` or `"main"`, but I think what I said above is the main problem with the part you are asking about.)

Answer (score 2):

You got a bug here

```
document.getElementById("logo").onclick = closeMenu();
document.getElementById("linkList").onclick = closeMenu();
document.getElementById("main").onclick = closeMenu();
```

You calling closeMenu, not assigning it.

Needs to be

```
document.getElementById("logo").onclick = closeMenu;
document.getElementById("linkList").onclick = closeMenu;
document.getElementById("main").onclick = closeMenu;
```

Answer (score 0):

Whoops, you're missing quotes around that `"navG"` in the first loop.

Comment: You're right, that does make the second alert work..however, there still seems to be nothing actually stored in menus. Adding an alert to the second for loop that is alert(menus[i]); returns nothing.

Comment: Are you seeing alerts in the second for loop? I feel like the `push` function isn't working properly.

Comment: jsfiddle.net/rtn8P

Another commenter seems to have found that it works here..there doesn't seem to be any real difference between that and my code.